# How to show the ten most recent rows from another sheet's timestamp?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-timestamp

In one sheet `A` I have an ongoing number of rows where the first column is a timestamp in ascending order (more recent entries at the bottom).

I'd like to have another sheet `B` where only the ten most recent entries (per timestamp) appear.

Is there a function that can achieve that?

<sub>If using the timestamp is not feasible, then the ten bottom rows, given that those will be the most recent.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps you can share a doc with us and show the expected outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another way of doing it.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(TIMESTAMPS!A:B, "SELECT A, B ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 10")
```

### Explained

The `QUERY` formula needs the data from the timestamps sheet, for it to process. The result must contain column A and B, of which column A is sorted descendingly (new to old). Finally, the result is limited to 10 entries (rows).

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[how to show the 10 most recent rows](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/12MT26nAsjVGSk73qA-g6Zdig3LlFef8yPbXDxdjEHRY/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results in rows1:10 please try:

```
=large('A'!$A:$A,11-row())
```

in Row1 and copy down to Row10. If in reverse order leave out `11-`. If in some other row either change `11-row()` to a number to represent which of the 10 belong in that row (`1` being the most recent, `2` the next most recent, etc) so each formula is individually tailored, or use an offset in the formula and then copy, so for the results to show starting in Row7 and continuing downwards use `17-row()` instead of `11-row()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since other answer appears not to suit, one adapted from [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309658/excel-2013-function-that-will-return-last-12-values-listed-in-a-column-every-tim):

```
=OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-10,0,10,1)
```